# How to get a list of all packages in a repository with specified package tyep(like npm, maven...) in Jfrog Artifactory using its API?

Tags: artifactory

I'm working on a project, used to collect package information from Jfrog Artifactory repositories. Now I wonder how to get a list of packages in a specified repo using jfrog rest api?

Note: I tried to use AQL, for example, item.find{...}, but it general return all related artifacts (not only package information).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all repositories of a specific package type, for example, Docker, try this URL:

```
curl -u username:password -X GET "https://artifactory.es/artifactory/api/repositories?packageType=docker"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GraphQL API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/GraphQL) for querying package information.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <access-token>" \
     -XPOST https://<your-domain>/metadata/api/v1/query \
     -d '{"query":"..." }'
```

See the documentation linked above for the syntax, available filters, and more.